# Does ASP.NET MVC routing have a way of distinguishing between ints and strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

Let's say I have two controller actions like

```
[Route("foo/bar/{id}")]
IHttpActionResult SomeController ( string id )
{
    // ... 
}

[Route("foo/bar/{id}")]
IHttpActionResult SameRouteAsAbove ( int id ) 
{
   // ... 
}
```

and I make a request to the URL `"foo/bar/123"`. Does IIS or whatever count this as a hit `SameRouteAsAbove` since the parameter is number-like even though it could be intended as a string representation of the number?

Comment: I feel like this is probably a design issue, but maybe you could try using {id:int} and {id:string} in your route attribute.

Comment: @DanHogan according to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) there is no string

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use ***regular expression***, and modify the way you want it.

***FYI:*** You will need to test all the possible scenarios. Otherwise, you will get run-time error if both routes match the given id.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values/1
    [Route("api/values/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetInteger(int id)
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }

    // GET api/values/abc
    [Route("api/values/{id:regex([a-zA-Z])}")]
     public IHttpActionResult GetString(string id)
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a Regx [a-zA-Z] where you could use {id:alpha} to the same effect? Check attribute constrains [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).

Comment: @Tarek Good catch. You can definitely use ***alpha*** in this saturation; I just want to show the general case.

Comment: Are you sure you'd get a run-time exception and not the mvc routing choosing the route that was registered first?

Comment: @ErikPhilips If we have typo in route registration such as `{id:re([a-zA-Z])}`, we will get compile-time error; they are very obvious and very easy to fix. In my experience, most of the routing exception throw at run-time which is a bummer.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you make the request saying `"foo/bar/123"` it's indeed part of the request query string and thus a `string` but it's your MVC `Model Binder` which will take responsibility to map the `id` value properly to your action method parameter type and thus it will get mapped per the type you have defined.

Per your posted code this would be ambiguity unless you specify the route separately. You can as well go one step further and define your `Route` value like

```
[Route("foo/bar/{id:int}")]
IHttpActionResult SameRouteAsAbove ( int id ) 
{
   // ... 
}
```